# Xamarin Android App Play Console Sensitive Permissions

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-console

I installed a new application to release it to the play console. I installed Apk. First, I uploaded it to the open beta channel, but it always seems to be under review.
Later, after installing each apk, I get an e-mail about application permissions, they say that they do not comply with their privacy and sensitivity policies.

These appear in the permissions required by apk on the play console:

**android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WAKE_LOCK, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE**

This is the content of mail:
Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app

You declared Select Carrier Services and Device Automation as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.

Please either:

Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality
Sensitive permission
Your app does not qualify for use of the requested permissions. Permission requests should make sense to users. You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes.

This is the my AndroidManifest.xml and permissions:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

If anyone has an idea or can help I would be very glad.
Although I changed it 8 times and installed the apk, I did not get approval for how many days and I constantly receive the mail I sent the content above, every time I send an apk..

Comment: Are you submitting a release build with linking enabled?

Comment: @Andrew linking assemblies only